# How to make Keycloak validate user consent?

Tags: validation, authentication, keycloak

In our NodeJS/React application we use Keycloak for authorization. We need to implement consents upon registration. We adapted all these layouts to our design system https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/3.4.3.Final/themes/src/main/resources/theme/base/login.
There is layout for registration form. We added the checkbox `<input type=checkbox name="user.attributes.registration_consent1" />` to the [appropriate layout](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/3.4.3.Final/themes/src/main/resources/theme/base/login/register.ftl).
If user registers and checks the checkbox I can confirm that related information is stored in Keycloak>Users>SomeUser>Edit>Attributes

[image: attributes table]
But still user can register without checking the checkbox. How to prevent user registration if he does not check the consent? I don't want to use JavaScript.

The [Terms and Conditions](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/3.4.3.Final/themes/src/main/resources/theme/base/login/terms.ftl) method is unacceptable because of bad user experience and conversion slowdown.

Answer (score 2):

After you've added your form field to your template, you'll need to validate user input. Validation also mean checking if a mandatory field was filled out by the user and also overwriting / adding data based on the value of that field.

*e.g. User checked "Terms & Conditions" but you need to store the timestamp of when those were accepted and maybe the version of the accepted "Terms & Conditions".*

**Relying on client side validation (HTML or JavaScript) is not the best solution.**

In this particular case you'll need to tell Keycloak how to validate the value of that new field.

This can be done by using Keycloak's Service Provider Interfaces (SPIs). In this case the Authentication SPI is responsible for handling registration form data.

Here is a link to that particular section in the docs:
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#modifying-extending-the-registration-form

Comment: Whats the option for login forms?

Answer (score 0):

You need to a required action. Under the admin, go to Authentication -> Required Actions tab. You can find there terms and conditions.

You probably need to edit the template of terms and conditions to match your theme and add the text you need the user to read. You usually find it under /login/terms.ftl

Result: user will not be registered if he declines the terms and conditions.

Comment: I suppose [this](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/3.4.3.Final/themes/src/main/resources/theme/base/login/terms.ftl) template should show up as second step of registration. It is unacceptable from the UX point of view and we don't want it this way. Another flaw is bad marketing flow. The registration of a user should be as fast and easiest as possible to convert it.

Comment: with some tweaking, there should be a way to integrate it into the registration page

Comment: Could You please elaborate a little? What is your specific idea when You say "some tweaking"?

Comment: Not sure, needs some research. Another way is use html form validation, in your case <input type=checkbox name="user.attributes.registration_consent1" required /> . This will show a pop that asks the user to check the checkbox. Here is an example: https://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-checkbox-required/